# Regular Expression for SINGLE digit in grep

Tags: regex, grep

I've been trying to get a regular expression for a SINGLE digit I need to extract from a file. Let's assume the file has numbers: `100, 10, 20, 35, 67, 8`. I only want `8`.
I tried

```
    egrep "[0-9]{1}"
```

but it still returns all the numbers in the file. If i do

```
    egrep "[0-9]{3}
```

it only returns 100. Why does it work this way?

Comment: Because `[0-9](1)` will match a single digit, and `100` is three single digits (a one, a zero and a zero), all of which meet the regex's specification. `[0-9]{3}` needs three digits in a row, so it won't match `1' (one digit), or `10` (twod digits), but matches `100` (which is three digits).

Comment: Thanks for this @KenWhite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you have the following 2 input files with numbers on the same line or on different lines as shown hereunder:

**INPUT:**

```
more digits*
::::::::::::::
digits2.in
::::::::::::::
100
10
20
35
67
8
::::::::::::::
digits.in
::::::::::::::
100,10,20,35,67,8
```

You can run the following `grep` command to fetch only the single digit (this work for both files):

```
$ grep -o '\b[0-9]\b' digits.in                                                                                                  
8
$ grep -o '\b[0-9]\b' digits2.in                                                                                                 
8
```

**Explanations:**

The regex `\b[0-9]\b` will match a single digit surrounded by word boundary character, the `-o` option is used to print only that result and not the whole line as the default behavior does.

In case there are several numbers composed of a single digit:

**INPUT2:**

```
more digits*
::::::::::::::
digits2.in
::::::::::::::
100
10
20
35
67
8
9
::::::::::::::
digits.in
::::::::::::::
100,10,20,35,67,8,9
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ grep -o '\b[0-9]\b' digits2.in 
8
9

$ grep -o '\b[0-9]\b' digits.in                                                                                                  
8
9
```

This will output all the numbers composed of a single digit.

Comment: Hmm thank you very much for this

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are separated by commas, try this:

```
    grep ",\d,"
```

(\d is the same as [0-9])

What that's saying is "match a comma, followed by a digit, followed by another comma". Since we just want numbers that are one digit, we need to have a start and end of the number, which can we classified by the commas.

Another option is:

```
    grep "\b\d\b"
```

What that's saying is "start searching at the beginning of a word, followed by a digit, and then the end of a word". A word is classified by [A-Za-z0-9]. If you want to look into \b more, it's called a word boundary.

Comment: Note that neither `grep` nor `grep -E` accepts `"\d"` for digits; you either have to write it as `"[0-9]"` or switch to the `grep -P` regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

With `[0-9]{1}` youre asking to match every digit because you actually do not define boundaries to your regex. If `grep` allows look behinds and aheads, you could use the following regex

```
(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    grep "^[0-9]$"
```

solves the problem. The key was the missing $ at the end. This indicates it should be a single digit